# Change data format in QGIS field calculator using format_date

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, date, format

I´d like to **change the data format** in the attribute table from yyyy-MM-dd (default) to dd.MM.yy using the `format_date` function in the field calculator.

Using:

```
format_date(date, 'dd.MM.yy')
```

I got NULL values in the new field in the attribute table.

My create a new field settings:

[image: create a new field settings]

Although the output review looks correct, in the new field only NULL values appear:

[image: null values]

Choosing string as the output field type the new field contains intended values but in the wrong format. 
Applying `to_date`expression on the string values is invalid.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, a date should be saved as a date - not string - and formatted on display. This format should be set at the column level, not at the cell (value) level, so outside of the field calculator expression.

One would open the layer property, find the field of interest and set the format of the `Widget Display` **only** (thanks to @Mapos  and @Kazuhito for this major detail!)

[image]

[image]

---

Let's note that there is potentially a bug / limitation (QGIS 3.4.5) if you also set the `field format` as it works for a date being edited and in Form View, but NOT when displaying all values in the attribute table...

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Mapos thanks! A bit counter intuive to not set the field format but only the widget format... I have integrated it to the answer

Comment: @Mapos What is QGIS 4.3.9? Isn't the newest version 3.28? I feel like I'm missing something here.

Comment: @JGH, enor: typing error