# QGIS 3 system date format is not assumed

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

The system date format is 'dd/MM/yyyy', and QGIS recognizes this on the Options / General tab, however it does not assume this format anywhere else in itself. Any loaded feature that has a date or datetime attribute has the format 'yyyy-MM-dd'. How to set QGIS 3 default date format so that it actually uses the system format?

[image: Date and datetime formats QGIS3]

Comment: Have you looked at the answer in this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330873/change-data-format-in-qgis-field-calculator-using-format-date?

Comment: Yes, but it is a different matter, I do not refer to attributes in a feature, but to the general settings of QGIS3 itself. Obviously, such settings would reflect the presentation of the date or datetime attributes of the features. The image links has broken, I fix.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a global setting for date format. You could make a feature request. https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues

Comment: ok, I'll open a request